# Execute multiple regular expressions against a string

Tags: regex, vba

My log files are about 15mb, and I've built off of a parser from a former employee.

What I'm trying to figure out is if it is possible to execute multiple (3 different) regular expressions against a string. I'm hoping to cut it down to one macro to save processing time, instead of running 3 different macros against the same log files.

Relevant Code:

```
Dim regEx, Match, Matches
Dim text1 As String
Dim text2 As String
Dim text3 As String
Dim text4 As String
Dim text5 As String
Dim text6 As String
Set regEx = New RegExp  ' Create a regular expression.
regEx.Pattern = "(?:user:\s.)(\w*)(?:].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\.*\n\s*.*\n)(\d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*)(?:.)(update)(?:\scfg_skill_level\sset\slevel_\s=\s)([\d])(?:\swhere\sperson_dbid\s=\s)(\d{4})(?:\sand\sskill_dbid\s=\s)(\d{4})" 'Set pattern.
regEx.IgnoreCase = True ' Set case insensitivity.
regEx.Global = False     ' Set global applicability.

Set Matches = regEx.Execute(strResult)    ' Execute regex search.

If Matches.Count > 0 Then
    For Each Match In Matches
        text1 = Match.SubMatches(0)
        text2 = Match.SubMatches(1)
        text3 = Match.SubMatches(2)
        text4 = Match.SubMatches(3)
        text5 = Match.SubMatches(4)
        text6 = Match.SubMatches(5)

        strTargetHr = Left(Match.SubMatches(1), 2)
        strTargetmin = Mid(Match.SubMatches(1), 4, 2)
        strTargetSec = Mid(Match.SubMatches(1), 7, 2)
        dtTargetTime = TimeSerial(Val(strTargetHr), Val(strTargetmin), Val(strTargetSec))
        If dtTargetTime < dtTimePlaceholder Then
            dtTargetDate = DateAdd("d", 1, dtDatePlaceholder)
        Else
            dtTargetDate = dtDatePlaceholder
        End If
        strTargetDate = Format(dtTargetDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")
        dtTimePlaceholder = dtTargetTime
        dtDatePlaceholder = dtTargetDate

        Selection.InsertAfter Chr(10) & strTargetDate & "," & text1 & "," & text2 & "," & text3 & "," & text4 & "," & text5 & "," & text6
    Next Match
End If
```

I've tried making one long regex combining the 3 expressions, which works [here](https://regex101.com/r/vT7eV0/2), but not in the macro.

Sample Output I've received from above:

```
07/23/2014,Joy,14:13:01.395,update,1,7151,4002
```

Comment: Perhaps it's just me, but: I see only one regular expression in your question. Where are the other 2 that you're talking about, and how do you want to combine them? What does your input data look like? Does the sample output you posted differ from what you expect? If so: how?

Answer (score 0):

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vT7eV0/4)

Notice I added capture group names this allows you to filter which type was found much much easier.

***Note:*** you're regex looks right make sure you are escaping the string.  just add a `@` in front of the `"` like below.

```
@"(?<search1>(?:user:\s.)(\w*)(?:].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\.*\n\s*.*\n)(\d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*)(?:.)(update)(?:\scfg_skill_level\sset\slevel_\s=\s)([\d])(?:\swhere\sperson_dbid\s=\s)(\d{4})(?:\sand\sskill_dbid\s=\s)(\d{4}))|(?<search2>(?:user:\s\[)(\w*)(?:].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\.*\n\s*.*\n)(\d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*)(?:\s)(delete)(?:\sfrom\scfg_skill_level\s\where\sperson_dbid\s=\s)(\d*)(?:\sand\sskill_dbid\s=\s)(\d*))|(?<search3>((?:user:\s\[)(\w*)(?:].*\n.*\n.*\n.*\.*\n\s*.*\n.)(\d*:\d*:\d*\.\d*)(?:\s)(insert)(?:\sinto\scfg_skill_level\s\()(?:.*\)\s\n\w*\()(\d*)(?:,\s)(\d*)(?:,\s)(.)(?:,\s)(.)(?:,\s)(.)))"
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, vbscript reference in word vba doesn't allow the use of capture group names.

Comment: @produbrian if this is the only function switching language would be my recommendation.